# How to revert website from previously localized version?

Tags: localization

I traveled abroad to Israel and loaded IE while there. My MSN homepage loaded the localized Hebrew version. Now I am back in the US and the homepage is still defaulting to the Hebrew one. I've already tried clearing cookies and restarting, but it doesn't resolve it. The homepage URL is displaying correctly in the tools setting.

I am on IE 11 and Win 8.1. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Have a look [Here](http://browsers.about.com/od/internetexplorertutorials/ss/Change-The-Default-Languages-In-Ie9.htm) this should help you change to the desired language.